# Is it possible to use Firebird Embedded for small number of users

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, firebird2.1, firebird2.5

I am using Firebird on Windows (Delphi 2010 developed Application).

Is it possible to use Firebird Embedded for small number of users?

http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html

If we have our application with embedded firebird on a single machine (on a LAN), could multiple users (12-25) use it. Each machine running the app, pointing to the firebird database embedded with the app on the single machine? Sharing the same database?

Or is the embedded version 1 user only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with Firebird 2.5 multiple Firebird embedded users can connect to the same database file simultaneously.

Comment: Andrei - it seems you are right. I read threough the release notes of 2.5 and it is indeed also part of the embedded version as well. http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes251.html

Comment: Accessing a single database using embedded from multiple machines is the road to database corruption and locking conflicts. Don't do it: use a server.

Comment: I believe, Firebird has introduced the new feature based on some usecase where it fits.

Comment: No, shared file access over the network should *never* be done with a Firebird database. You simply risk corruption because most likely the lock-file will be local to each individual computer!

Answer (score 1):

Although the Firebird 2.5 allows multiple *applications* on a *single machine* to access a single database file with embedded, this should **not** be done for multiple users accessing a single database file over a LAN with embedded.

It could easily lead to corruption of the database due to sharing and locking problems. If you want to access a Firebird database over the network: use Firebird server. It is easier, most likely more performant and it won't corrupt your database file.

You don't even need a server system to run it, depending on your exact needs and load, a normal desktop machine should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use standard (not embedded) version? It is very lightweight.

Comment: Maintenance? I've thinking of this same approach, except for just 1-5 users.

Comment: Firebird is a "zero maintenance database" ;)

Comment: by maintenance he means the chore of installing the server and keeping track of which is the server with multiple network installations. With a shared database on the network you just fire up any number of clients and they all work without needing a server.